# Text and hyperlink in one cell (clickable text)

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, hyperlink, runtime-error

There are 3 ranges of cells. The second range contains the addresses of hyperlinks. In the third range I want to have the text in the first range, but by clicking on it the hyperlink was activated.

In this line:

```
Perem1 = book1.ActiveSheet.Range("110+A,iLoop*(25+B)")
```

This error occurs:

> Run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object defined error .

Full code:

```
Sub vopros()

    Dim book1 As Workbook
    Dim Perem1 As String
    Dim Perem2 As String
    Dim iLoop As Long

    Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("E:\Super M\Проект ставки\Поиск решения\Усов 7\Условия для андердогов\пробная.xlsm")
    book1.Worksheets("Лист1").Activate

    iLoop = 0

    Do

    iLoop = iLoop + 1

       For A = 0 To 4
          For B = 0 To 65

       Perem1 = book1.ActiveSheet.Range("110+A,iLoop*(25+B)").Value
       Perem2 = book1.ActiveSheet.Range("185+A,iLoop*(25+B)").Value

      book1.ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("34+A,iLoop*(25+B)"), Address:="Perem1", TextToDisplay:="Perem2"
       Next
   Next
   Loop Until iLoop = 4

End Sub
```

Comment: It seams you are using `"` where they shouldn't exist. As I can see, from `Do` downwards, all double quotes should be removed.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ, did't help , same error in the same place